# Stream-chaining

Tags: api, go, stream

My goal is to have a reusable pattern for doing concurrent stream-processing in Go.

- The stream has to be closable from any node.
- Errors should cleanly close the stream and forward the error to the consumer.
- Should have a nice API

Here's what I came up with: http://play.golang.org/p/DSIPmKiAst

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "log"
)

type Item struct {
    val string
    err error
}

type Stream struct {
    in    chan Item
    close chan bool
}

func (s Stream) Close() {
    // send the close signal
    s.close <- true
    // drain any remaining Item's from the stream
    for _ = range s.in {
    }
}

func NewWordStream(words []string) Stream {
    s := Stream{make(chan Item), make(chan bool)}
    go func() {
    loop:
        for _, w := range words {
            select {
            // if we get a close signal, break the loop and close the channel
            case <-s.close:
                break loop
            // wrap the word in an Item and send it on the channel
            case s.in <- Item{w, nil}:
                continue
            }
        }
        close(s.in)
    }()
    return s
}

func (s Stream) Map(fn func(string) (string, error)) Stream {
    out := make(chan Item)
    go func() {
        erroring := false
        for item := range s.in {
            // ignore all items while erroring
            if erroring {
                continue
            }
            // if Item is an error, forward it, and start erroring
            if item.err != nil {
                erroring = true
                out <- item
                continue
            }
            // run the transformation function
            val, err := fn(item.val)
            // if the transformation returns an error, forward it and start erroring
            if err != nil {
                erroring = true
                out <- Item{"", err}
                continue
            }
            // everything went ok, forwarding transformed string
            out <- Item{val, nil}
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return Stream{out, s.close}
}

func (s Stream) Do(fn func(string) error) error {
    var err error
    for item := range s.in {
        // when an error Item is recieved, save the error and close the stream
        if item.err != nil {
            err = item.err
            s.Close()
            continue
        }
        // otherwise invoke the callback with the item
        if e := fn(item.val); e != nil {
            err = e
            s.Close()
            continue
        }
    }
    return err
}

func main() {

    // stream items
    words := []string{"this", "is", "pretty", "cool", "1", "2", "3"}

    // producer
    stream := NewWordStream(words)

    // transformation function
    wrap := func(s string) (string, error) {
        if s == "cool" {
            return "", errors.New("not cool")
        }
        return "<" + s + ">", nil
    }

    // consumer
    show := func(w string) error {
        log.Print(w, " ")
        return nil
    }

    // do it!
    if err := stream.Map(wrap).Do(show); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error: %s", err)
    }
}
```

It'd appreciate any criticisms and suggestions for improvement.